# how to get parent id by using a child id in hierarchy?

Tags: c#, asp.net, hierarchy

```
Item 01
  Item 01 01
  Item 01 02
     Item 01 02 01
     Item 01 02 02 <-----
     Item 01 02 03
  Item 01 03
Item 02
  Item 02 01
  Item 02 01
```

I'm using asp.net and C#.
This is my main menu. I want to show some item of main menu in left sidebar menu. for example if a user selected [Item 01 02 02] i want to show all sub menu items of [Item 01] in left sidebar menu.
I access to the id of [Item 01 02 02].

thanks for any idea.

Comment: Is this using the built-in Menu control?

Comment: Please provide something for us to work with. What have you tried?

Comment: no, no, i'm generating menu by li tag and css. my problem is i can't find parent id of selected child id. if i get that id i'm able to solve it.

Comment: Are you trying yo access a parent item inside a click event handler? Maybe a little bit of code will help to understand what are you trying to do, and in what context.

Comment: thanks istepaniuk, I've done. it's not a server control, it's just div tag that creates from database records.